# How to tell if a Shopify store is using Online Store 2.0 theme?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm building a Shopify app

I want to know if a majority of potential clients are using Online Store 2.0 themes or not.

Is there a way to tell this by looking only at their websites? (i.e. checking if some script is loaded in network tab that only loads for online store 2.0 themes)

Comment: Nope. Since Shopify compiles themes and dumps HTML, JS, and CSS, there really is nothing in there special to OS 2. Build your App for it. OS 1 is crap and dead, and even though people use it, moving forward, you'll be better off just focusing on OS 2 I bet.

Comment: @DavidLazar I was literally JUST reading your answer to another Shopify post. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

On the Shopify Product reviews sample app, they have this endpoint, which returns whether the current theme supports app blocks (only 2.0 themes support app blocks)

```
  /**
   * This REST endpoint is resposible for returning whether the store's current main theme supports app blocks.
   */
  router.get(
    "/api/store/themes/main",
    verifyRequest({ authRoute: "/online/auth" }),
    async (ctx) => {
      const session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(ctx.req, ctx.res);
      const clients = {
        rest: new Shopify.Clients.Rest(session.shop, session.accessToken),
        graphQL: createClient(session.shop, session.accessToken),
      };

      // Check if App Blocks are supported
      // -----------------------------------

      // Specify the name of the template we want our app to integrate with
      const APP_BLOCK_TEMPLATES = ["product"];

      // Use `client.get` to request list of themes on store
      const {
        body: { themes },
      } = await clients.rest.get({
        path: "themes",
      });

      // Find the published theme
      const publishedTheme = themes.find((theme) => theme.role === "main");

      // Get list of assets contained within the published theme
      const {
        body: { assets },
      } = await clients.rest.get({
        path: `themes/${publishedTheme.id}/assets`,
      });

      // Check if template JSON files exist for the template specified in APP_BLOCK_TEMPLATES
      const templateJSONFiles = assets.filter((file) => {
        return APP_BLOCK_TEMPLATES.some(
          (template) => file.key === `templates/${template}.json`
        );
      });

      // Get bodies of template JSONs
      const templateJSONAssetContents = await Promise.all(
        templateJSONFiles.map(async (file) => {
          const {
            body: { asset },
          } = await clients.rest.get({
            path: `themes/${publishedTheme.id}/assets`,
            query: { "asset[key]": file.key },
          });

          return asset;
        })
      );

      // Find what section is set as 'main' for each template JSON's body
      const templateMainSections = templateJSONAssetContents
        .map((asset, index) => {
          const json = JSON.parse(asset.value);
          const main = json.sections.main && json.sections.main.type;

          return assets.find((file) => file.key === `sections/${main}.liquid`);
        })
        .filter((value) => value);

      // Request the content of each section and check if it has a schema that contains a
      // block of type '@app'
      const sectionsWithAppBlock = (
        await Promise.all(
          templateMainSections.map(async (file, index) => {
            let acceptsAppBlock = false;
            const {
              body: { asset },
            } = await clients.rest.get({
              path: `themes/${publishedTheme.id}/assets`,
              query: { "asset[key]": file.key },
            });

            const match = asset.value.match(
              /\{\%\s+schema\s+\%\}([\s\S]*?)\{\%\s+endschema\s+\%\}/m
            );
            const schema = JSON.parse(match[1]);

            if (schema && schema.blocks) {
              acceptsAppBlock = schema.blocks.some((b) => b.type === "@app");
            }

            return acceptsAppBlock ? file : null;
          })
        )
      ).filter((value) => value);

      /**
       * Fetch one published product that's later used to build the editor preview url
       */
      const product = await getFirstPublishedProduct(clients.graphQL);
      const editorUrl = `https://${session.shop}/admin/themes/${
        publishedTheme.id
      }/editor?previewPath=${encodeURIComponent(
        `/products/${product?.handle}`
      )}`;

      /**
       * This is where we check if the theme supports apps blocks.
       * To do so, we check if the main-product section supports blocks of type @app
       */
      const supportsSe = templateJSONFiles.length > 0;
      const supportsAppBlocks = supportsSe && sectionsWithAppBlock.length > 0;

      ctx.body = {
        theme: publishedTheme,
        supportsSe,
        supportsAppBlocks,
        /**
         * Check if each of the sample app's app blocks have been added to the product.json template
         */
        containsAverageRatingAppBlock: containsAppBlock(
          templateJSONAssetContents[0]?.value,
          "average-rating",
          process.env.THEME_APP_EXTENSION_UUID
        ),
        containsProductReviewsAppBlock: containsAppBlock(
          templateJSONAssetContents[0]?.value,
          "product-reviews",
          process.env.THEME_APP_EXTENSION_UUID
        ),
        editorUrl,
      };
      ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
    }
  );
```